# rotate a single page

Tags: graphics, page

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{logicarch.pdf}
\caption{system architecture}
\label{fig:logiarch}
\end{figure}
...
```

I wish the figure and its caption, could be horizontal placed in a single page, unlike the rest which is vertical. Besides, I also noticed the pdf exported from visio have a large blank at its bottom, is there a way to 'cut' it a little or 'autofit' according to the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sidewaysfigure`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\includegraphics[width=20cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{system architecture}
\label{fig:logiarch}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\clearpage
\section{Some vertical page starts here}
\end{document}
```

Comment: may I change the direction? now it faces right.

Comment: Yes, just put `\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}` instead of `\usepackage{rotating}`.