# How do you rotate just one page in Overleaf?

Tags: tables, landscape

[image]I have a table in a latex document that is too wide, so I am trying to use `pdflscape` to rotate the page it's on, but as soon as I add `\usepackage{pdflscape}`, all of the text in the entire document is rotated. Using `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}` around the table in question does nothing and there are no other instances of a landscape command anywhere. I don't understand why all of the contents are being flipped and not just the part between the `begin` and `end` commands. If it is relevant, this is a `twocolumn` document in Overleaf with these packages: `mathtools, amsmath, pdflscape, geometry`. Here is a skeleton of the TeX code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,linenumbers]{aastex631}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{pdflscape}
% \usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\affiliation{My School}

\section{Results}
% \newgeometry{margin=1cm}
% \begin{landscape}
    \begin{deluxetable*}{CCC}[htb]
        \tablecolumns{3}
        \tablecaption{Data}
        \tablehead{\colhead{col 1} & \colhead{col 2} & \colhead{col 3}}
        \startdata
        0 & 1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4 & 5 \\
        6 & 7 & 8
        \enddata
        \tablecomments{}
    \end{deluxetable*}
% \end{landscape}
% \restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: pdflascape should not rotate any pages by default, but for your use case probably better is to use rotating package and the sidewaystable environment

Comment: Rotating one page is independent from LaTeX engine and editor ... Show us small but complete document, which reproduce your  problem.

Comment: possible duplicate -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414867/rotate-a-single-page

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was using the aastex format. They provide a `\rotate` function that goes inside the deluxe table

```
\begin{deluxetable*}
\rotate
\startdata
...
```